# Could not find method android causing R error in my code

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:(15, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_41ptob9czd5ucux9ngzednsn4$_run_closure1@100eeb5] on root project 'ud839_Miwok-Starter-code'.
Open File

i have also tried rebuilding the gradle with internet connections on still yet,

below is my build.gradle code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

android {
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `build.gradle` file belongs to project level. please move below lines to **module** `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
}
```

[Detailed ref is here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#build-files)